# Batching and padding using the Tensorflow data API

Tags: python, tensorflow, padding, tensorflow-datasets, batching

I'm having trouble understanding how the TensorFlow data API (tensorflow.data.Dataset) works. My
input is a list of lists of integers that I want to batch, pad
and concatenate. E.g my data looks like this

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1]]
```

with batch size 3 it should become:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 0, 0]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 0]],
 [[1, 0, 0]]]
```

and finally:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski How do you transform the data from the input format to the output format using the `tensorflow.data` API.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I did not get it the first time. Is this how you get the data in, as such lists? I am asking since likely you will have to process the data outside TF to get the desired shape (rectangular data).

Comment: @LukaszTracewski The data is in a more complicated format but to simplify the question I've described it as lists of lists. I hope the tools in `tensorflow.data` should be enough to transform it into the structure I want.

Comment: What you have there can be converted to a `RaggedTensor`, which is not supported by `padded_batch`. IMO you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't easy, but I finally got it to work:

```
def batch_each(x):
    return Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(3)
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1]]
rt = tf.ragged.constant(data)
ds = Dataset \
    .from_tensor_slices(rt) \
    .flat_map(batch_each) \
    .padded_batch(1, padded_shapes = (3,)) \
    .unbatch()
for e in ds:
    print(e)
```